# fetch pdf from iBooks to my app

Tags: ios, ibooks

is there a way to list pdf documents stored in iBooks from my iPad app ?

The pdf would be first uploaded in the iPad through iTunes and then my app would list the titles. Clicking on a title would open the pdf in iBook.

Cheers,

Tib.

Answer (score 4):

No. All apps are sandboxed and cannot access each other's data unless there is a specific API for it. Since that is not the case for iBooks, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This was not possible in the past. It's now available using Document Picker on iOS. The only is that the app which stored the doc should implement this feature. This is the case for iCloud, Dropbox ...

This is not possible for iBooks since Apple doesn't want to support document picker for iBooks ...