# Get files/Documents directory from iBook to my app

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fetch pdf from iBooks to my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866515/fetch-pdf-from-ibooks-to-my-app)

I need to list the files that are in iBook directory.
What is the iBook files/documents path(directory) in the iPad device?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible. For security purposes apps are not allowed to touch each other's document directories.